# Kibana Visualization Split Chart Question

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-8

I have two side by side visualizations in Kibana that are the exact same, just with different filters. They both "Split chart" on the same field, which has a cardinality of 30. There are generally more records in the left visualization, which means for that time frame there are more splits in the chart. I was wondering if there was a way to fix the number of splits in both charts to always include 30 splits. That way even if there's no data for that specific time frame for certain groupings, there would still be an empty chart there. The goal is to have the left and right visualizations be symmetrical so that they're easier to read back and forth.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You probably need to select `size: 30` + enable show missing value for both of your charts and also always order your keys alphabetically. Can you try and see what this yields?

Comment: I think it's just a coincidence that there are only 5 splits on the right side and the default size is 5. The size is set to 30. The reason it is only showing 5 is because those are the only 5 values with any data for that time range. I would like the other values that don't have data during that time to still have an individual bar chart, even though they will be empty.